# Не проигрывает mp3

Tags: android, exoplayer

Пытаюсь реализовать проигрывание mp3 потока из интернета через ExoPlayer. Нашел пример в интернете и делаю по нему, но ничего не получается. Подскажите где что не так?

```
public class Player extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private String stream;
    private String radio;
    private int rec;

    private ImageButton btnStop;
    private ImageButton btnPLayPause;
    private ImageButton btnRecord;

    private ExoPlayer player;
    private PlayerControl playerControl;

    MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer audioRenderer;
    private static final String TAG = "SimpleExoMp3";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        btnStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        btnPLayPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPLayPause);
        btnRecord = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRecord);

        //Получаем текст из списка и ссылку на радио
        stream = getIntent().getExtras().getString("stream").toString().trim();
        radio = getIntent().getExtras().getString("radio").toString().trim();
        rec = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("rec");
        //Устанавливаем заголовок Activity
        setTitle(radio);

        player = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(1);

        String url = "http://radio.kavkaz.fm/balkarian.mp3"; //Url for your mp3 file
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url); //Convert that to uri
        player = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(1); // new Exoplayer instance, only one render, as we're playing only audio, in case of video
        // we need two renders, one for audio and one for video
        DataSource dataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(this, TAG); // this instance is reqd to pass data to exoplayer
        ExtractorSampleSource extractorSampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(uri, dataSource, new DefaultAllocator(64 * 1024), 64 * 1024 * 256);
        //ExtractorSampleSource is used for mp3 or mp4, uri is passed, datasource is passed, a DefaultAllocator instance is also passed)
        // to know more about this go on exoplayers (see description for links)
        audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(extractorSampleSource, MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT);
        //here we prepare audioRenderer by passing extractorSampleSource and MediaCodecSelector
        player.prepare(audioRenderer);
        // finally we prepare player
        playerControl = new PlayerControl(player);
        //then we get controls of the player, play and pause
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.btn_play){
            //on play button click
            if(!playerControl.isPlaying()){
                player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            }
        }else if(v.getId()==R.id.btn_pause){
            //on pause button click
            if(playerControl.isPlaying()){
                playerControl.pause();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        //before destroying the app
        super.onDestroy();
        player.release(); // important otherwise song will play even after app has closed.
    }
}
```

В логах только выводится следующее

```
I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
D/AudioTrack: Client defaulted notificationFrames to 3675 for frameCount 11025
```

В gradle прописал следующее compile `'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.8'`

А в манифест добавил разрешение на интернет

Comment: попробуйте какой-нибудь другой аудифайл воспроизвести или с другого сайта

Comment: Все равно не проигрывает